# Will ExecutionEngine.execute(String,Map<String,Object>) prevent "NoSQL Injection Attacks"?

Tags: prepared-statement, neo4j, sql-injection, cypher

So, I've used PrepareStatements in SQL based databases via JDBC to prevent against SQL injection attacks.

I want to know if using Neo4J's Java API `ExecutionEngine.execute(String,Map<String,Object>)` (see [1](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j-cypher/1.6.1/apidocs/org/neo4j/cypher/javacompat/ExecutionEngine.html#execute%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29)) prevent injection attacks against Cypher if used properly?

To elaborate, if the substition of the parameters is performed early and then the Cypher is parsed, I can't see how this would help protect against injection attacks, but if the Cypher is parsed and then the parameters are substituted later, then I could see how it would protect against injection attacks.

It's well known that PrepareStatements in JDBC/SQL will protect against NoSQL attacks, and I want to ensure that using `ExecutionEngine.execute(String,Map<String,Object>)` will provide me with the same level of protection.

Thanks!!

Barry

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's not a simple string substitution, it actually gets parsed first, the query object is cached, and then parameters are filled in. This is good for performance, too, as it doesn't need to reparse queries when just the parameters are changed.

Comment: On http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-parameters.html, Brad wrote "Ah ok that makes sense, thanks Peter. I guess I was thinking of parameters more in terms of protection from Cypher injection attacks, I guess in these cases I should just write my own safeguards?"

and was answered by Peter Neubauer who wrote "Yes,
that is probably the easiest solution for the time being :)".

Can anyone comment on this? It seems in direct contradiction to the answer above.